# Create dataframe from unique vectors of differing lengths in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have an R dataframe, titled `tab`, like the following:

```
StoreID    Sales    ZIP    day
1          4900     55401  1/1/1993
1          3121     55401  1/2/1993
3          10021    90210  1/1/1993
3          50000    90210  1/2/1993
13         12000    12312  1/1/1993
```

...

The number of unique `StoreID` values is 40, while the number of unique `ZIP` values is 25. I basically want a dataframe of length 40, with just the StoreID and ZIP codes.

This is basically what I've tried:

```
ID_ZIP <- data.frame(unique(tab$StoreID))
for(i in unique(tab$StoreID)){
  dat <- tab[StoreID == i]
  append(unique(tab$Zip))
}
```

And I've kind of gotten stuck. I'm used to key-value iterations in Python.. Would `merge` be the right way?

Edit:
The result set:

```
StoreID    ZIP
1          55401
3          90210
13         12312
```

...

Comment: how about `unique(subset(tab,select=c(StoreID,Zip)))` ?  I can't quite tell if this will work/gives you what you want -- reproducible example would be nice.

Comment: You would have to first determine what you would like to do with the cases with multiple zips for the same store. Are you just selecting the first?

Comment: @PierreLafortune, I *think* each store can only be in one ZIP code (assuming that the OP is referring to US postal codes ...)

Comment: More than one store can be in a given ZIP code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `unique()` function works on data.frames.

I'm guessing you just mean this?

```
tab<- read.table(text="StoreID    Sales    ZIP    day
1          4900     55401  1/1/1993
1          3121     55401  1/2/1993
3          10021    90210  1/1/1993
3          50000    90210  1/2/1993
13         12000    12312  1/1/1993", header=T)

unique(tab[,c(1,3)])

  StoreID   ZIP
1       1 55401
3       3 90210
5      13 12312
```

or more explicitly:

```
unique(tab[,c("StoreID","ZIP")])   

StoreID   ZIP
    1       1 55401
    3       3 90210
    5      13 12312
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always try SQL to tackle this by using the `sqldf` package:

`sqldf("SELECT StoreID, ZIP FROM tab GROUP BY StoreID, ZIP)`

Comment: Thanks. I already had my data from MySQL Workbench, though. I'll give that a shot next time.

Comment: Yeah try it. If you know your SQL then `sqldf` makes it easy.